# Blender is freezing while editing and playing the animation

Tags: animation, error

I use blender for creating animations for The Sims 4. I worked on 2.70 version and it was perfect until one day. I opened the program as usual, but it didn't run at all. Firstly, I redownloaded it several times, but nothing changed. Then, I found an answer on the forum saying that I need to download the opengl32.dll file and put it into the program's folder. So did I and Blender started working. However, it started freezing and this was really annoying me. When I deleted the opengl32.dll file, program stopped running (eventually).

All I know that this is not my computers' power issue, since I have really powerful PC with 32 GB RAM and Nvidia GeFore 1070 8 GB videocard. My OS is Windows 10.

My questions is: What can I do to solve this problem?

UPD: I've tried to update the Blender to the newest one, but nothing have changed.

Comment: Update to the current version of blender and see how that works out, you shouldn't need to download anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I found the answer. I deleted the opengl32.dll file from newest version of the Blender and it started working as it used to before these problems. To test this "method" I rebooted my PC, and Blender worked perfectly. I hope this won't change anymore.